# Limit of an expression involving exponentials, trignometrics, and polynomials using the maclaurin series

Tags: calculus

[This is what I've tried to do so far, but I can't get to the point where the denominator cancels out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZgFe.jpg)

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ where
$$
 f(x) = \frac{e^{x^{2}} \sin x - x \left(1+\frac{5 x^2}{6}\right)}
{x^{5}}
$$

Comment: please paste the contents of the link and writeup a short version of the question.

Comment: That's pretty much it: the function diverges to $-\infty$ roughly like $-x^{-2}$, since $e^{x^2}\to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem statement**

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$ where
$$
 f(x) = \frac{e^{x^{2}} \sin x - x \left(1+\frac{5 x^2}{6}\right)}
{x^{5}}
$$
The function is plotted below.

[image: f(x)]

**Building blocks**

$$
\begin{align}
%
 e^{x^{2}} & = 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{x^8}{24}+O\left(x^9\right) \\
%
 \sin x &= x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^9\right)
%
\end{align}
$$

**Assemble numerator**

$$
 e^{x^{2}} \sin x = \color{blue}{x}+\color{blue}{\frac{5 x^3}{6}}+\frac{41 x^5}{120}+\frac{461 x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^9\right).
$$
Polynomial part cancels lead terms.
$$
e^{x^{2}} \sin x - \color{red}{x} - \color{red}{\frac{5 x^3}{6}} = \frac{41 x^5}{120}+\frac{461 x^7}{5040}+O\left(x^9\right)
$$

**Denominator**

The effect of the denominator is to reduce powers in the numerator by $5$.

**Final Series**

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{e^{x^{2}} \sin x - x \left(1+\frac{5 x^2}{6}\right)}
{x^{5}}
= 
\frac{41}{120}+\frac{461 x^2}{5040}+O\left(x^4\right) \\[5pt]
\end{align}
$$

**Limit**

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 
\lim_{x\to 0}  \left(
\frac{41}{120}+\frac{461 x^2}{5040}+O\left(x^4\right)
\right) = \frac{41}{120}
$$